# Settings up database association with three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Alright, I am trying to set up my associations in the user model as well as columns in my tables.

I have three models, `User`, `Position`, and `Group`.

**user.rb**

```
belongs_to :position
belongs_to :group
```

**group.rb**

```
has_many :positions
has_many :users, through: :positions
```

**position.rb**

```
belongs_to :group
has_many :users
```

Essentially, each user belongs to a position and a group. And each position belongs to a group. So I can easily find a user's position by `user.position` and find their group by `user.position.group`.

In the database, the `Position` table has a `group_id` column and the `User` table has `position_id` and `group_id` column.

The objective of these associations is this: If I change a user's `position` (`position_id`) to something, it should automatically change that user's `group` (`group_id`) to that associated group. Right now, if I change the user's `position`, I can find their *new* group by `user.position.group`. However, I'd prefer to make it where I can just call `user.group`, which would mean the user's `group_id` would have to change as I changed their `Position`.
'

If anyone can shed some light to the *best* way to do this, as well as the logic and reasoning behind it, it'd be greatly appreciated. [The Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) have helped get the associations to the current state, but I know I'm missing something like an `index`. Thank you.

Comment: This feels like a circular association, which creates problems keeping things in sync, as you've immediately discovered.  Why does user need to be directly associated with a group?  Can't you just associate them with a position and then look up their group via the position?

Comment: Yea definitely. I can do that, as I am now...I just didn't know if that was the *most efficient* way to do it.

Comment: I would say that it is sufficiently efficient.  Leave "optimisations" (especially ones that make your schema more complicated) until there is a need for it, and keep it simple for now.  That's my advice anyway.  See pragmatic mantras "KISS" and "YAGNI" :)

Comment: I appreciate it. ha yea Keep it simple stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your user.rb model:

```
after_update :set_group_id

# At the bottom of user.rb

private
  def set_group_id
    self.update(group_id: position.group.id)
  end
```

Basically, each time you update the user, it will update the group_id to match the user's position's group id. (I also agree with an above comment, this database structure is circular and I would caution against this).